# Django: how to include a meta tag in only 1 template

Tags: django

When User registers successfully, I will display a thank you page.

This page will have a meta tag to redirect after 5 seconds to home.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/"/>
```

However, I need to place it inside the thank you page, that extends from base. Not in base, so not other pages make this redirect.

thank you page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% block metadescription %}
    {% if category %}
        {{ category.description|truncatewords:155 }}
    {% else %}
        ¡Bienvenidos a Stickers Gallito Perú!
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    <p>Stickers Gallito - Confirma tu correo electrónico</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">


        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h1> ¡Gracias por registrarte! </h1>

        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Stickers Gallito Perú">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.google.com/"/>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="fGkwUY2RcijkVzB6DiwIuAToP1y5xw8ECXQQabRAOIM"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="{% static 'js/footer.js' %}"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div class="general-container">

</div>


{% include 'navbar.html' %}

{% if has_shop_in_url %}

    {% include 'header.html' %}

{% endif %}


{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the head of your base.html include

```
{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
```

Then in your page

```
{% block extra_head %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/"/>
{% endblock %}
```